# How to connect to git repository in a remote Linux machine using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: linux, git

I have a git repository installed in a remote Linux server, but would like to work on it and sync my changes to the git repository using Visual Studio Community Edition 2017.

Apologies if this is a repeat question; am new to this and have looked at the existing answers on SO but don't seem to have found a direct answer for this.

I have managed to use Team Explorer to connect directly to github, but would prefer to connect to the git repository on the Linux server instead.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not clone locally, and manage the commits, etc. from a command prompt? (this has the added benefit of giving you control over when your changes are pushed). Are you asking how to automate that within VS2017 itself? The connection itself doesn't care whether you connect to github or a remote Linux box -- that's simply a matter of authentication.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin, do you mean that VS2017 is able to connect directly to a remote Linux box? Which feature in VS2017 is able to do this? I tried using the Team Explorer feature and it seems to be able to connect only to github repo links. In other words I would like to configure VS2017 to connect to the local git repo within the Linux server (i.e. what I am doing now with Notepad++), but am not sure how to do so

Comment: I wish I could tell you exactly how to do it within VS, but I don't use VS (I have it, it was just always twice as cumbersome to use, so I prefer the developer command prompts). What I was saying is "if you can connect to github in VS2017, then there is no reason you can't connect to any box with a git repository." (github just runs on top of Linux, so the only question of "can you connect?" is whether you have the correct user/pass or public/private key that allows you to connect) I have 2 Linux servers hosting git repos. I also use github. There isn't any difference in how I connect.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a user on the linux machine, with a `projects` subfolder in your home directory, and under that you have a git project in a folder called `myproject`.

You should be able to run `git clone username@server:projects/myproject` at any remote terminal (including windows with git installed), assuming you have an ssh server enabled on the linux `server` above (you may have to install openssh-server first).

Comment: I get what you are saying, but how does that relate to VS2017?

Comment: Thanks @activedecay. Yep, not too sure how I can run these commands within VS2017.